Riemann Integration and Supremum
Suppose we have $f(t, \mathbf{s}): \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{g}$ where
$\mathbf{s} \in [0, 1]^{g}$ with $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \cup \infty$,
$t \in \mathbf{t}$ where $\mathbf{t}$ is a set of tagged point on an arbitrary interval $[a, b]$ and $t_{i}^{(n)}$ represents the element at $i$-th position of the set $\mathbf{t}$, $\lvert\mathbf{t}\rvert=n$ ,
and $f$ is a continuous function and differentiable on such interval $[a, b]$ w.r.t. $t$ and $\forall s \in \mathbf{s}$.
Here is what I have:
$$
\begin{align*}
    &
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n}
    \sup_{\mathbf{s} \in [0, 1]^{g}} 
            f(t_{i+1}^{(n)}, \mathbf{s})
            -
            f(t_{i}^{(n)}, \mathbf{s})
    \\
    =&
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n}
    \sup_{\mathbf{s} \in [0, 1]^{g}} 
        \frac{
            f(t_{i+1}^{(n)}, \mathbf{s})
            -
            f(t_{i}^{(n)}, \mathbf{s})
        }{
            t_{i+1}^{(n)}
            -
            t_{i}^{(n)}
        }
        (
            t_{i+1}^{(n)}
            -
            t_{i}^{(n)}
        )
    \\
    =&
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n}
    \sup_{\mathbf{s} \in [0, 1]^{g}} 
        \frac{d}{d{\bar{t}_{i}(\mathbf{s})}} \left[ 
            f(\bar{t}_{i}(\mathbf{s}), \mathbf{s})
        \right]
        (t_{i+1}^{(n)} - t_{i}^{(n)})
    &\begin{split}
    &\text{(Mean Value Theorem)} \\
    &\text{($\bar{t}_{i}(\mathbf{s}) \in [t_{i}^{(n)}, t_{i+1}^{(n)}]$)}
    \end{split}
    \\
    \geq&
    \int_{b}^{a}
    \sup_{\mathbf{s} \in [0, 1]^{g}} 
    \frac{d}{d{t}} 
    \left[ 
        f(t, \mathbf{s})
    \right]
    d{t}
    &
    \text{(Riemann Integration)}
    \enspace .
\end{align*}
$$
Is there any chance that the second to the last holds for equality? If it can, what property that the function $f$ (or its derivative) need to have?
